# Questions about the Class method "forName()"

Tags: java, class

How do I let the user insert a String and check for classes with the same "name"?

Imagine I have a method marked as `public A[] getB(String bString)` and two classes, `A` and `B`, where `B extends A`.

In this method I want to **search through** an existing `A[]` for objects that are **upcast** from being from the `class B` and **return** an `A[]` with said objects.

I searched through the internet and found out that the class `Class` has the method `forName()`, but I don't really understand how to use it. For example, I do this:

```
Class<?> cl = Class.forName(bString);
```

Where `bString` is a `String` that contains `B`, `B` being **another class**.

My questions are:

- What exactly is the object "cl" now?
- How could I now check if objects are of the same class as it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly is the object "cl" now?

`cl` is an instance of [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class.

> How could I now check if objects are of the same class as it?

you have 2 object `o1` and `o2` you can use [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--)

```
o1 != null && o2 != null && o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass())
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Class.forName(String)` returns a `Class` object for the corresponding class, if known. To quote from its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-):

> Returns the `Class` object associated with the class or interface with the given string `name`.

An example would be:

```
Class threadClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");
```

Note that the name of the class needs to be **fully qualified**, not just `Thread` but `java.lang.Thread`.

The object you are getting is, as said, a representation of the corresponding class. You can use it to dynamically create instances, check methods, and so on. Here is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and here is an example:

```
Class<?> threadClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");

// Dynamically create a thread, unchecked cast
Thread thread = (Thread) threadClass.newInstance();
```

---

You can check whether two objects are of the same class by using the `getClass` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--)) method which every object has:

```
if (first.getClass().equals(second.getClass()) {
    // Same
} else {
    // Different
}
```

However note that this comparison is **strict**. It would throw `false` if you compare `Integer` and `Number` although `Integer extends Number`. If you want a less strict variant you may use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (first instanceof second) {
    // Is type of
} else {
    // Not type of
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you wouldn't rather use `isInstance`?

You could change your method to take a Class instead of a String, since that's what you're really using, a Class.

```
public A[] getB(Class type){
    // I'm assuming you have an array of all As somewhere, called Aarray here
    List<A> BList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < Aarray.length; i++){
        if(type.isInstance(Aarray[i])){
            BList.add(Aarray[i]);
        }
    }
    return BList.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the point here was to get the String from the user and go on from there. This would work but it would still miss the middle-point from string to class. Someone already answered with what I was looking for if you want to check it out, I marked it.